# Session variable caches value

Tags: .net, asp.net, session-variables

Is it advisable to use Session variables to pass data between aspx pages on the same domain?

I don't want to use Get and I'm not finding any workaround to pass Post data programmatically. 
I tried using WebClient [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx] but then it's not redirecting it to the url which is what I want.

My scenario is; after the log in page I want to pass few secret data to my landing page.

I read it somewhere that Session variable caches data, is it true? Can I use session variables to store data in my case? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Session to save User relevant informations. For example you can save the User-Id in his session object. Do you need more informations ?

Comment: That is what I intend to do. Is there any performance over head if I store a information in Session variable? Can I override the data in the session variable, are you sure it won't be cached?

Comment: Yes you can do this. But be aware of too much data in your session. On every request the Session object must build by the Server. Do you have a Session Database ?

Comment: I typically store around 4 name-value pairs in Session. Do I need to make a Session Database for this?

Comment: Thats not much data. I dont mean you need a session database. I only want to know it to understand from where the data comes. You only need a Session Database if you have multiple webservers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Session variables to store data. (OR) You can pass the value to another page by using QueryString...